# Should you use two definite articles in "the Wigner-Ville and Li-Katar distributions"?

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles, parallelism

Which one is right?

> - the Wigner-Ville and Li-Katar distributions
> - the Wigner-Ville and the Li-Katar distributions

Assume that both *Wigner-Ville* and *Li-Katar* are distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is correct, but the first is more compact and, to me, appears to be emphasizing that similarities are bieng emphasized while the second gives more separation between them, like you may be contrasting them...not really a gramatical thing, just my impression when reading them...perhaps *over* reading them...